# Docker layer does not exist

Tags: linux, docker

I have a Dockerfile that has `FROM ...` and `ADD` as arguments called `base` and `config`, respectively. It also has an `ADD installer.sh` in it.

However, while trying to build this using a single command, it throws an error saying: `layer does not exist` when I try to create the layer 2 as shown in this script invoked with `bash -c "source <script> && docker_build_layer_2"`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat <<'EOF' >variable-base.dockerfile
ARG base

FROM ${base} as intermediate

SHELL ["/usr/local/bin/bash", "-c"]

ARG config

ARG command

RUN mkdir -p /apps

ADD installer.sh /apps/

ADD ${config} /apps/

WORKDIR /apps

RUN source installer.sh && eval "${command}"
EOF

touch config-1.ini

touch config-2.ini

docker_build_layer_base()
{
    echo "INFO: Setting up layer:base from bash:latest"
    docker pull bash:latest
    docker tag bash:latest layer:base
}

# Supports any dockerfile that has `FROM $base`.

docker_build_layer()
{
    local dockerfile=$1
    local base=$2
    local config=$3
    local tag=$4
    echo "INFO: Setting up layer $tag"
    docker build \
        --build-arg base="$base" \
        --build-arg config="$config" \
        --file "$dockerfile" \
        --network host \
        --tag "$tag" \
        .
}

docker_build_layer_1()
{
    docker_build_layer_base &&
    docker_build_layer \
        variable-base.dockerfile \
        layer:base \
        config-1.ini \
        layer:1
}

docker_build_layer_2()
{
    docker_build_layer_1 &&
    docker_build_layer \
        variable-base.dockerfile \
        layer:1 \
        config-2.ini \
        layer:2
}
```

Surprisingly, this error goes away if I combine the `ADD` to a single line:

```sh
ADD installer.sh /apps/

ADD ${config} /apps/
```

to

```sh
ADD installer.sh  ${config} /apps/
```

Is this some weird cache issue possibly connected to this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21215)?

**Docker Version**: 19.03.13-ce, build 4484c46d9d

**OS**: Linux (Arch and CentOS)

---

**Disclaimer**

Please run this script in a separate folder as it **creates** some files and docker images (`layer:base`, `layer:1` and `layer:2`) as part of testing. It also pulls the `bash:latest` image. If you get an error, `layer:2` might not be present but a container might be present instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: BTW, I suggest to avoid using `ADD` and use `COPY` instead. `ADD` might perform some operations that you're not expecting: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

Comment: @Stefano, surprising, What is your docker version?

Comment: 19.03.3-rc1, build 1576bd7917